# -bash: initdb: command not found

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, .profile

I have installed PostgreSQL using the EnterpriseDB installation.

I ran `sudo ./postgresql-9.3.5-3-osx.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh --mode unattended` and then ran `open /Applications/TextEdit.app .profile` to edit my .profile file newly created in /Users/Dhruv to add the line `source /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/pg_env.sh.`

Running `createuser Dhruv --pwprompt --username=postgres` I got

> -bash: createuser: command not found

Then running `unknown-88-1f-a1-1b-c2-ec:9.3 dhruv$ sudo -u postgres /bin/createuser` and various other methods I was able to set up something using some sort of password prompt. I know this later because using `sudo -u postgres /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/createuser` I got

> createuser: creation of new role failed: ERROR:  role "postgres" already exists

Running then `initdb -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data I get`

> -bash: initdb: command not found.

Similiarly, if I try the same thing but while connected to postgres, `sudo su - postgres` and then `initdb -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data` I get again

> -bash: initdb: command not found.

At a loss at what to do. 1) how do I know details of this supposed role "postgres" I created magically and 2) why is initdb not working?

Answer (score 5):

How I fixed this is run `brew doctor`, and you might see the postgresql un der the Warning: that indicates there's unlinked kegs in your Cellar. 
Try to run `brew link postgresql`. It will show some symlinks got created. Then run `init db ...` again.

Hope this help!

Comment: Worked for me. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

Who are you logged in as?

When you do sudo or su -, it will run init scripts for root, such as .bashrc and .bash_profile.

These may set up difference executable search paths between root, postgres, and you.

Try something like `sudo initdb`, or `su - postgres -c initdb` ... whichever user has the paths constructed correctly, so that the path gets set up.

You could also duplicate the path/lib creation code in your own environment, but that will break if it is ever changed.

Comment: How do I find out who I am logged in as? In my own shell I have unknown-88-1f-a1-1b-c2-ec:bin dhruv$. I tried both what you said, for 'sudo initdb' I first got asked for a password then I got 'sudo: initdb: command not found'. For 'su - postgres -c initdb -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data' I got 'Password:' as a prompt, then whatever I type in I get 'su: Sorry'.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. I'm new to OS X coming from Linux, here's what I had to do. I installed postgres via homebrew and when I did so I noticed it put everything it download to: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/($postgres_version)/

When I cd'd into that folder I saw a directory named bin so I cd'd and saw initdb right there. So I had to then add this to my path so I could use the command:

$ export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.4/bin:$PATH

hope that helps you

Comment: I don't know about PostgreSQL, but normally with `homebrew` you only ever add `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH as it symlinks from there to the Cellar. I would respectfully suggest you check that and consider running `brew doctor` too to health check yourself. Later on, when you do `brew upgrade xyz` the symlink in `/usr/local/bin` will change automatically to the new version for you whereas your PATH with a version number in it will not...